# Laravel вычесть два withsum

Tags: laravel

```
$vatr =Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')->get();
```

Есть такой запрос, как в этом запросе сделать так чтобы вместе с ними приходила их разность т.е. solds.quantity - purchases.quantity.

На одном из форумов посоветовали следующее решение

```
 $titles = Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')
            ->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(purchases.quantity) - SUM(solds.quantity) as net_quantity')
            ->paginate(20);
```

Помогите с решением

Comment: И? в чём проблема? Решение имеет место быть.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'purchases.quantity' in 'field list'

Comment: Потому что Вы не правильно колонки называете. Если читать документацию, то метод возвращает название колонки другое!!! В данном случае будет колонка `solds_sum_quantity` и `purchases_sum_quantity` их и подставляйте в selectRaw `purchases_sum_quantity - solds_sum_quantity`

Comment: через дамп переменной $vatr можно посмотреть точное название двух этих колонок. Та же история работает и с withCount(...)

Comment: $vatr = Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')
        ->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')
        ->selectRaw('purchases_sum_quantity - solds_sum_quantity as net_quantity')
        ->paginate(20);
Так я сделал и до того как Вы сказали тоже. Ошибку выдает:  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'purchases_sum_quantity' in 'field list'         не видит такого поля

Comment: select `titles`.*, (select sum(`solds`.`quantity`) from `solds` where `titles`.`id` = `solds`.`title_id`) as `solds_sum_quantity`, (select sum(`purchases`.`quantity`) from `purchases` where `titles`.`id` = `purchases`.`title_id`) as `purchases_sum_quantity`, purchases_sum_quantity - solds_sum_quantity as net_quantity from `titles` limit 20 offset 0

Answer (score 1):

Может кому понадобится решение:

```
$titles = Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')
            ->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')
            ->paginate(20)
            ->through(function ($item) {
                $item->left_in_stock = $item->purchases_sum_quantity - $item->solds_sum_quantity;
                return $item;
            });
```